# rhc set-env gives NoMethodError

Tags: openshift

When trying to set or list environment variables using rhc, this error shows up instead. I tried reinstalling the gem, but this doesn't resolve the error.

```
*****@DESKTOP-RMLK74E ~> rhc set-env CREDENTIALS-FILE=~/app-root/data/credentials.json
/home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/helpers.rb:580:in `exe?': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/git_helpers.rb:37:in `block in discover_git_executable'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/git_helpers.rb:36:in `select'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/git_helpers.rb:36:in `discover_git_executable'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/git_helpers.rb:15:in `has_git?'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/git_helpers.rb:85:in `git_config_get'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/context_helper.rb:138:in `from_local_git'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:311:in `block in fill_arguments'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:302:in `each'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:302:in `fill_arguments'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:281:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/runner.rb:419:in `run_active_command'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:72:in `run!'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/delegates.rb:8:in `run!'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in `start'
    from /home/*****/.gem/ruby/gems/rhc-1.38.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/*****/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
    from /home/*****/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What version of rhc did you install?

Comment: 1.38.4, as indicated by the error message.

Comment: Sorry.  I was thinking of the Ruby version. What version of Ruby are you running?

Comment: I know that 2.0+ is buggy on windows. I'm on 2.0. I know 1.93 is good also.  Try 2.0

Comment: Didn't manage to compile 2.0 on RVM. Tried with 1.9.3 and still got the same error.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  It was worth a shot.  Every time I have read a post about Ruby and rhc issues it's been about the Ruby version.

Comment: Actually, I realized RVM didn't switch to Ruby 1.9.3 on fish. When I started a bash prompt and used rhc from there, it worked fine.

Comment: You should lost as an answer for the next person,:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ruby version 1.9.3 fixes the problem. Hope that RedHat releases a 2.2+ compatible version eventually.